# Eclipse won't open after installing openjfx

Tags: eclipse, javafx, java, openjfx

I was attempting to use JavaFX, and I found that I needed to install the `openjfx` package, as the regular `openJDK8` didn't come with the JavaFX files. However, since I did that Eclipse no longer opens. Instead, it crashes with the following crash log appearing: [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b5720ec35ee59f5d56f7709a99f70ed4).

OS: Linux (amd64) / Deepin 15.5